# Float is returning null in datasnapshot loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Well, I am trying to retrieve rating data from `Firebase` in order to calculate the average of the `rating bar`. Below is the code for retrieving data.

```
DatabaseReference ratingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rating");

ratingRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        double count = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            //Toast.makeText(RibsAndPowerboats.this, "it is "+ds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            double rating = Double.parseDouble(ds.child(RandomID).child("rating").getValue().toString());
            count = count + rating;
        }
        double avarage = count / snapshot.getChildrenCount();
        if (avarage == 0) {
            ratingBar.setRating(avarage);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RibsAndPowerboats.this, "it is" + avarage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException();
    }
});
```

Here is the SubmitRatingActivity:

```
String RandomID = getIntent().getStringExtra("RandomID");

if (RandomID != null){

    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rating");

    SubmitScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            float RatedValue = ratingBar.getRating();
            databaseReference.child(RandomID).child(userId).child("rating").setValue(RatedValue);
            String SaveReview = AddReview.getText().toString();
            String ScoreStrg = Float.toString(RatedValue);
            Score.setText(ScoreStrg+" out of 5");
            databaseReference.child(RandomID).child(userId).child("review").setValue(SaveReview);
            Toast.makeText(SubmitRating.this, "Ευχαριστούμε!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SubmitRating.this, RibsAndPowerboats.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my firebase database:

```
"Rating" : {
    "3086181c-c391-4bab-a022-0a0e0bb2624c" : {
      "Xqve54QUwwPo3NyZhcs2z4wkETB2" : {
        "rating" : 4,
        "review" : "Βδησηαησησσησησ"
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to change variables from double to float and long but nothing changes. What is the problem? The error that shows up is:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Please also show more than a single child node, so we have more context on what you're reading. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did it buddy. Thanks for the detailed comment!

Comment: Thanks. What's the exact value of `RandomID`? Can you also reproduce the problem if you hardcode that value? If so, please show the code with the hardcoded value, so that we don't have to trace the variable.

Comment: It should be possible to find out which object being printed is `null` especially examining what line it's at with the stack trace.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't know how to hardcode the value. But when I open the app it crashes and shows the error I attached above.

Comment: @clwhisk It is at this line `double rating = Double.parseDouble(ds.child(RandomID).child("rating").getValue().toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to get the values of the "rating" property within all User objects, please use the following lines of code:

```
String randomId = "3086181c-c391-4bab-a022-0a0e0bb2624c";
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference randomIdRef = rootRef.child("Rating").child(randomId);
randomIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String rating = snapshot.child("rating").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", "rating:" + rating);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be all the values of the `rating` property that exist under each User object.

Comment: Since the JSON in the question shows `rating` as a number, wouldn't `snapshot.child("rating").getValue(String.class)` return `null`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, that's correct. My bad, just updated my answer.